# How to add a 20px div above a header background image (with Fiddle)

Tags: html, css

On the top of my page I have a background image as below ( http://jsfiddle.net/VnXxj/3/ )

```
<div id="header">
Register/Login
</div>

#header {
    background: url("image.png") repeat-x scroll center bottom;
    height: 37px;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Instead of increasing the image's height in Photoshop, is there any way to add a 20px height div above the image?

I tried  `background: url("image.png") repeat-x scroll center bottom #888888;` but the image it has a transparent ending and it mess it.

Thank you for this

Comment: you could also do background: url("image.png") 0 20px repeat-x; }. this will not change the size of the div (keep it 37px in height), only will start drawing the image after 20px from top. you could also add padding-top:20px and total height will become 57px, with 20px image gap at the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try: `#header { margin-top:20px; }`

Comment: `#header {
    background: url("image.png") repeat-x scroll center bottom #888888;
    height: 24px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}` This what I have now from your suggestion that it is not working. It was moved down 20px but the colour #888 is not ABOVE the image is IN the image.

Comment: I'm kind of confused as to what you want, can you setup a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to show us what effect you're looking for? From what i understand you want some margin space in between the header and a logo correct?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/VnXxj/4/

EDIT: You might find this more useful as well. It's a bit more dynamic. http://jsfiddle.net/VnXxj/6/